# Is it possible to create a poll in facebook Group using restFb?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Is it possible to create a poll and fetch groupmembers polls from facebook Group using restFb

Comment: Your question it's too broad, be more specific about you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is now possible via Graph API.

The `question` endpoint was removed after version 1.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/question